# Multiple Fontstyles

Tags: c#, fonts

Is it possible to create a new font pragmatically with `Fontstyle.Bold` and `FontStyles.Oblique`?

Although `FontStyles.Oblique` isn't recognized as a method for me (Import a system?) :(

Comment: Uhm, what? Can you elaborate on what are you trying to achieve exactly, what have you tried and didn't work as expected?

Comment: `Oblique: Neither parallel nor at a right angle to a specified or implied line; slanting`.  Did you mean Font.Italic?

Comment: Italic it is... I have 2 `checkbox` 's each the ability to set the text to bold or italic. When both checked it should be bold AND italic. Just another mystery to be solved

Comment: Winforms? Web? WPF? etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is to set the font both **bold** and *italic* (i.e. ***both***). Then you can use

```
FontStyle newFontStyle = new FontStyle();
newFontStyle = FontStyle.Regular;
newFontStyle = FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Italic;
```

I hope this helps.

*Note. This is assuming you are using WinForms.*

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to mention this is for windows form apps :)